# Como acesso o contêiner Docker recebendo mensagem de erro ao executar o comado exec

Tags: docker

Eu estou tentando acessar os contêineres e estou recebendo a seguinte mensagem de erro:

> OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused "exec: \"bash\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown

Como eu posso proceder para resolver esta falha no acesso?

Comment: Sua pergunta não tem pé nem cabeça.

Comment: Olá Richard. Qual o comando você está usando exatamente para receber este erro? Se possível, dê detalhes também de qual imagem docker você está usando em seu container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O erro é claro: O arquivo `bash` não pôde ser encontrado.

Possíveis problemas são:

1. A [variável `$PATH`](https://www.vivaolinux.com.br/artigo/O-que-e-PATH-como-funciona-e-como-trabalhar-com-ele) não está devidamente definida para encontrar
   o binário.
2. A imagem utilizada em seu container realmente não possua o
   `bash` disponível.

Para resolver o primeiro caso, tenta chamar pelo caminho completo (o caminho pode variar dependendo da imagem base). Um exemplo:

`docker exec -it meu-container /bin/bash`

O `bash` não estar disponível é bem comum em imagens que utilizam Alpine Linux como imagem base, pois estas não possuem o `bash` instalado por padrão. Uma alternativa neste caso é utilizar o `sh` ou instalar o `bash` em seu container.

**Para usar o `sh` execute:**

`docker exec -it  meu-container sh`

Se preferir o `bash`, adicione a instalação em seu `Dockerfile` e gere uma nova imagem.